# Matthews correlation coefficient as a loss in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to write a custom loss function for keras with tf backend.
I get the following error

> ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure
>   that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are
>   differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round,
>   K.eval.

```
def matthews_correlation(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
    y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos

    y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
    y_neg = 1 - y_pos

    tp = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos)
    tn = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg)

    fp = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)
    fn = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_neg)

    numerator = (tp * tn - fp * fn)
    denominator = K.sqrt((tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn))

    return 1.0 - numerator / (denominator + K.epsilon())
```

If I use this function as a metric and not as the loss function it works. How can I use this function as a loss?

After removing K.round I get following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1,
>   got 8
>      [[{{node loss_9/dense_10_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   squeeze_dims=[-1],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]
>   (_arg_dense_10_sample_weights_0_2/_2445)]]
>      [[{{node loss_9/add_12/_2467}} = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6418_loss_9/add_12",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Comment: `K.round` is not differentiable. Can you try without rounding so we can narrow the error surface?

Comment: @JosefKorbel it won't work. any thing that use tp and tf (such as f-beta) is not a loss and as such won't be viable.  you won't be able to use it as a loss. you need to use it as metric and keep this to get the best iteration.

Comment: @tag please update your answer, don't post useful infos in comments

Comment: @Alexis oh I fear that you're right. Wont be so usefull as you cannot directly minimize it tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: **You can't**

let me explain a little why. First we need to define a few things:

- loss: a loss function or cost function is a function that maps an event or values of one or more variables onto a real number intuitively representing some "cost" associated with the event. An optimization problem seeks to minimize a loss function
- metric: 
  In mathematics, a metric or distance function is a function that defines a distance between each pair of elements of a set
- optmizer: a way to optimize (minimize) a cost function.

now why can't we use the True positive rate as a loss function?
Well because you can't minimize it. It is not convex. So you can't define the cost of the prediction individually. As you can see from the definition it's a cost function that depends on all the answers to calculate a rate. You can't calculate it for 1 sample.

**What you can do?**

use it as a metric and use early stopping while following the evolution of this metric and get the best iteration.

Comment: Why should convexity matter?  Deep learning is a type of non-convex optimization.  Sorry for jabbing you, I just don't wan't people to be confused. Anyway, my answer links to a differentiable loss function for MCC.

Answer (score 3):

@Alexis has already given the answer to the error message, but I want to clarify something about loss functions which are derived from metrics:

In general metrics can not be used as loss functions, but often smoothed version of metrics like the dice measure (=F1 score) [CH Sudre 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03237) can be applied as loss functions. One usecase might be image segmentation.

(Please excuse, that I have to add this comment as an answer, since I do not have enough reputation to add a comment)

Answer (score 1):

This pre-print describes a differentiable loss function for the Matthews Correlation Coefficient. They derive an analytical form for its gradient, based on differentiable versions of TP, FP, etc.  Then they use it to train their Convolutional Neural Network.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.13454

I think these formulas are exactly what you need.   They provide code in PyTorch, too.